# Powershell move all download to another folder function

Tags: python, powershell

I want to create a function to move file to a folder  depending on the type of the file "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Telechargement" to specific folder

I want to have the equivalent of this for PowerShell:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Telechargement"):
```

My PowerShell function:

```
 function DeplacerDansBonDossier {
            param (
                $extension
            )

        foreach ($file in $files) {
            $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($line)
            if ($extn -eq ".txt" )
            {
                Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Documents"
            }

            elseif ($extn -eq ".mp3" )
            {
                Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
            }

            elseif ($extn -eq ".wav" )
            {
                Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
            elseif ($extn -eq ".mp4" )
            {
                Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
            }

            elseif ($extn -eq ".mkv" )
            {
                Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a `switch` statement would be a better use here. Wheres the `$lines`, and `$files` variable coming from? Also, what is your question? Are you passing it an file argument? A folder path? Please add more detail in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes without saying that there are lots of ways to accomplish this.  You may not need a function at all as these files could be piped directly to a `ForEach-Object` loop.  At any rate, if we are using a function I would start by sending the collection of `[FileInfo]` objects generated by `Get-ChildItem` to the function.  This is in place of the extension.

That might look something like this:

```
Function DeplacerDansBonDossier {
    param (
        $Files
    )

foreach ( $file in $files ) {
    $extn = $File.Extension
    
    if ($extn -eq ".txt" ) {
        Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Documents" 
    }
    elseif ($extn -eq ".mp3" ) {
        Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
    }
    elseif ($extn -eq ".wav" ) {
        Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
    }
    elseif ($extn -eq ".mp4" ) {
        Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
    }
    elseif ($extn -eq ".mkv" ) {
        Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
    }
}

} # End Function DeplacerDansBonDossier
```

In your demo code you had the extension, but you didn't have the file object on hand so effectively there was nothing to move.

Another variation using the switch statement as @AbrahamZinala suggested:

```
Function DeplacerDansBonDossier {
    param (
        $Files
    )

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $extn = $File.Extension
    
    Switch ($extn)
    {
        '.txt' { Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Documents"; Break }
        '.mp3' { Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique";   Break }
        '.wav' { Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique";   Break }
        '.mp4' { Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo";     Break }
        '.mkv' { Move-Item -Path $File -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo";     Break }
    }    
}

} # End Function DeplacerDansBonDossier

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\SourceFolder

DeplacerDansBonDossier $Files
```

Obviously `Switch` makes things more concise, but not as descriptive.  Also, note the `break` statements. Unlike `If\ElseIf` a `Switch` statement will evaluate more than 1 condition and script block.  We stop that behavior with `Break`

Not to be redundant, but there's a lot more that could be done here.  For example we could pipeline enable the function so it can be piped right after `Get-ChildItem`, but it may not be worth it considering aforementioned potential of `ForEach-Object` would operate much the same.

**Example with `ForEach-Object`:**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\SourceFolder |
ForEach-Object{
    foreach ( $file in $files ) {
        $extn = $File.Extension
        
        if ($extn -eq ".txt" ) {
            Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Documents" 
        }
        elseif ($extn -eq ".mp3" ) {
            Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
        }
        elseif ($extn -eq ".wav" ) {
            Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
        }
        elseif ($extn -eq ".mp4" ) {
            Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
        }
        elseif ($extn -eq ".mkv" ) {
            Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I wouldn't use `Switch` in the `ForEach-Object` script block. `$_` operates differently in a `Switch` context.

Note: None of this is tested. You may need to use the `.FullName` property for the `-Path` argument, either `$File.FullName` or `$_.FullName`. the `*-Item` cmdlets can be fussy in that way.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. This function will only accept **Files** as input, note that I'm using `Get-ChildItem -File` below. Another point to consider is that, if there is a `File` with the same name on the Destination Folder `Move-Item` will throw with the following error:

`Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

You can use `-Force` if you want to replace the existing files or add a new condition there if there is an existing file with the same name.

```
function DeplacerDansBonDossier {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(mandatory,valuefrompipeline)]
    [System.IO.FileInfo]$File
)

    begin
    {
        $Paths = @{
            Documents = "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Documents"
            Music = "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
            Video = "C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
        }
    }
    
    process
    {
        switch -Regex($File.Extension)
        {
            '^\.txt$'{
                $File | Move-Item -Destination $Paths['Documents']
                Write-Verbose ('Moved {0} to {1}' -f $file.Name,$Paths['Documents'])
                break
            }

            '^\.mp3$|^\.wav$'{
                $File | Move-Item -Destination $Paths['Music']
                Write-Verbose ('Moved {0} to {1}' -f $file.Name,$Paths['Music'])
                break
            }

            '^\.mp4$|^\.mkv$'{
                $File | Move-Item -Destination $Paths['Video']
                Write-Verbose ('Moved {0} to {1}' -f $file.Name,$Paths['Video'])
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use the function:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Telechargement' -File | DeplacerDansBonDossier

# If you want to see which Files are being moved and their destination
# you can use -Verbose
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\dgoud\Desktop\TP4\Telechargement' -File | DeplacerDansBonDossier -Verbose
```

Comment: Looks like we crossed paths again (no pun intended). Love the `-RegEx` addition to consolidate some of the switch blocks +1.

Comment: Not sure but we may want to escape the "." and perhaps add anchors `^` & `$`. Probably only for edge cases but I'd imaging there's some potential for funky extensions.

Comment: @Steven you're right, didn't think about that. I added the anchors and `.` escape. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other great answers already, if the extensions always map to those paths, storing them in a hash table could be used here.

```
function DeplacerDansBonDossier {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $File,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Username = $env:USERNAME
    )

    begin {
        $extensionDestinationMappings = @{
            ".txt" = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\TP4\Documents"
            ".mp3" = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
            ".wav" = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\TP4\Musique"
            ".mp4" = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
            ".mkv" = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\TP4\VidBo"
        }
    }

    process {
        $extension = $File.Extension

        # Check extension exists in hashtable beforehand
        if ($extensionDestinationMappings.ContainsKey($extension)) {
            Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $extensionDestinationMappings[$extension] 
        }
    }
}
```